# Not able to find child component on shallow/mount , after adding React UID

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ui-automation

For UI automation, I am trying to add unique id for React component.
before adding the ID, my test cases are [passing for finding child component.
but after adding id with:

```
  <Fragment>
     <UIDConsumer>    
       { (id  => <div id={id} >
       <CustomComponent/> 
       </div>})
    </Fragment>
```

in my jest Unit test, is failing

```
 wrapper = mount(
            <Provider>
              <ViewComponent/>
            </Provider>
          );
      it("CustomComponent component", () => {
            const CustomComponent = wrapper.find(CustomComponent);
            expect(CustomComponent).to.have.lengthOf(1);
      });
```

Comment: A unit test should receive value for custom components 1 but received 0 instead.

Comment: I followed https://codeburst.io/unique-ids-and-where-to-find-them-14020ddbc964, an example to generate id